# How can i use small text editor like this one in html page

Tags: php, html, text-editor

I am looking for simple and nice looking text editor like this one

[image]

on this page http://www.quora.com/How-can-you-use-Python-with-Mahout-as-you-can-with-Hadoop-Streaming at the bottom. which editor is that one.

I don't like tinymce and its looks

Comment: you can do this by javaScript which  cant be explain here it will going long code

Comment: There are many other choices, and I don't think you can't apply a custom style. Anyway I think this is not a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to customize the editor options... Go through to the following links.. hope it will help you...:)

1. http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/20-excellent-free-rich-text-editors/
2. http://ckeditor.com/demo (Click on Custom toolbar)
3. http://nicedit.com/demos.php?demo=2

Answer (score 1):

I, personally, would suggest this YouTube video tutorial (Part 1, search up Part 2 yourself): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSAQK4Nwkm4. It teaches you how to make a WYSIWYG (what you see is what you get) rich text area. That might help.

Just tweak the styles and stuff yourself, and you can get something that is exactly like what is above.